# Оптимизация парсинга Python

Tags: python

Нашел интересный заказ на парсинг.
**Задача:** спарсить поисковую выдачу (она ограничена 8 выдачу).

Заказчик хочет чтобы **последовательно** (а значит в 1 поток) вводить в поиск символы, и парсить результаты и как только результата не будет (или дойдет до предела), менять последнюю букву на следующую.

**Символы:** a-z, 0-9 и знак -.

**Ограничение поиска:** 63 символа

**Пример:**

```
a - результат есть, спарсили
aa - результат есть, спарсили,
aaa - результат есть, спарсили
aaaa - результата нет, меняем букву
aaab - результат есть, спарсили
aaaba - результата нет, меняем букву
aaabb ..... 
И так далее, ограничение только в 63 символа
```

Допустим, имеются точно результаты на любые 3 символа. 
Значит количество запросов составит 38 в 3 степени = 55к запросов. Допустим 1 запрос в секунду = 15 часов. А если будут из 4 символов, то это уже 2млн запросов как минимум (и в 1 поток)

Долго, нужно переделывать в многоточность и уговорить **возможного заказчика**.

**Мое возможное решение:**
Делаем все варианты символов до ограничения в 63 символа и начинаем парсить.
Как только наша совокупность символов не находит результата, то удаляем из общего символа все цепочки, которые начинается на наш запрос и длиннее нашего.

**Пример**

```
aaaa - результата нет, меняем букву, удаляем все:
aaaaa,
aaaab,
aaaac,
....
aaaaaa,
aaaaab,
.....
aaaaaaa,
aaaaaab
и т.д.
```

Отсюда возникают вопросы:

1. В чем хранить? Потребляемая память, быстрота поиска и удаления в середине списка или другого типа данных.
2. Как синхронизировать пул потоков на время удаления одним потоком из общей переменной, предназначенной для хранения общего списка

Думаю использовать requests + threedPoolExecutor, или вообще использовать async + aiohttp

Также думаю можно попробовать создать задачи (async) и передать первоначальные символы (1 символ - запрос), если нашелся результат, возвращаем в паук, а там создаются новые задачи, только уже с 2 символами (38 вариантов) и т.д.
Думаю это даже предпочтительней.

**Выслушаю любые предложения по решаемой задаче)**

**Update:** Накидал тут тестовый код, с имитацией запроса (ожидание 1 секунды), и ограничением в 4 символа (4 символа нет результата), заняло 475 секунд

Вот доделал, но не могу обойти защиту:

```
import os
import time
import logging
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from contextlib import suppress

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
format = '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s:%(message)s'
logging.basicConfig(format=format, level=logging.INFO)

count_thread = os.cpu_count()

limit = asyncio.Semaphore(20)
limit_char = 63
# chars = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z', '1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','-']
chars = ['a']




"https://zen.yandex.ru/api/v3/launcher/suggest?from_person=&clid=300&country_code=ru&_csrf=c82e9d15e08190fc560c5a1c4311718e1dcd2e71-1553723057191&token=&page_type=catalog_suggest&search_text=a&rnd=1553729595244"
async def request(client, text):
    r_text = ""
    url = "https://zen.yandex.ru/api/v3/launcher/suggest"
    global limit, headers
    async with limit:
        headers = {
            'Host': 'zen.yandex.ru',
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0',
            'Accept': '*/*',
            'Accept-Language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
            'Referer': 'https://zen.yandex.ru/search',
            'Zen-Features': '{"no_amp_links":true,"forced_bulk_stats":true,"blurred_preview":true,"big_card_images":true,"complaints_with_reasons":true,"pass_experiments":true,"video_providers":["yandex-web","youtube","youtube-web"],"screen":{"dpi":241},"need_background_image":true,"color_theme":"white","no_small_auth":true,"need_main_color":true,"need_zen_one_data":true,"interests_supported":true,"return_sources":true,"screens":["feed","category","categories","profile","switchable_subs","suggest","blocked","preferences","subscribers","blocked_suggest","video_recommend","language","send_app_link_sms","comments_counter","social_profile","social_activity_feed","social_profile_edit","social_interests_feedback","profile_onboarding_status","profile_complete_onboarding"],"stat_params_with_context":true,"native_onboarding":true}',
            'Zen-Client-Experiments': 'zen-version:2.76.5',
            'Connection': 'keep-alive',
            'Cookie': 'elFKCQHOHQcwSly6JK45WVMePVsUYKWR3IUSpMtierqvrhnFAYkV3ZTJ45lcVLPWKnUzZp4pWPHeyEM8AKh'
        }
        data = {
            'from_person':'',
            'clid':'300',
            'country_code':'ru',
            '_csrf':'c82e9d15e08190fc560c5a1c4311718e1dcd2e71-1553723057191',
            'token' : '',
            'page_type':'catalog_suggest',
            'search_text': text,
            'rnd':'1553729691869'
        }
        try:
            async with client.get(url, headers=headers, data=data) as r:
                log.info("Статус: %s  - %s", r.status, text)
                if(r.status == 200):
                    return [await r.text(), text]
                else:
                    log.info("Ошибка статус: %s", r.status)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)



def parse(block):
    text_list = []
    result = ["RESULT"]
    json = block[0]
    print(json)#Обработка json и получения result
    text = block[1]
    # print(text)
    # if(len(result) > 0):
    #     if(len(text) < limit_char):
    #         for char in chars:
    #             text_list.append(text + char)
    return text_list


async def crawl(future, client, pool):
    futures = []
    urls = await future
    for request_future in asyncio.as_completed([request(client, url) for url in urls]):
        parse_future = loop.run_in_executor(pool, parse, (await request_future))
        futures.append(asyncio.ensure_future(crawl(parse_future, client, pool)))
    if futures:
        await asyncio.wait(futures)

async def start_main(root_urls):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    with ThreadPoolExecutor(count_thread) as pool:
        conn = aiohttp.TCPConnector(ssl=False)
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=conn) as client:
            initial_future = loop.create_future()
            initial_future.set_result(root_urls)
            await crawl(initial_future, client, pool)






if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_time = time.time()
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    # loop.set_debug(True)
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(start_main(chars))
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        for task in asyncio.Task.all_tasks():
            task.cancel()
            with suppress(asyncio.CancelledError):
                loop.run_until_complete(task)
    finally:
        loop.close()
    print("Время работы парсера:", time.time() - start_time)
```

Кто может помочь, с обходом защиты?

Comment: А допустим, символов всего до 8 будет  (это сильно меньше ограничения) и потоков допустим будет 1000 (нормально же?). Символов 37 на самом деле (26+10+1). Считаем - 37^8 / 60/60/24/365/1000 = около 111 лет. упс. может решается проблема XY? и проще сделать по словарю? Но думаю, Вы забыли ключевое слово dns. тогда все ограничения понятны.

Comment: @KoVadim а ну да, 37. Что значит решать по словарю? И я не понял про dns

Comment: По поводу ограничения, ну по любому такого не может быть, 3-4 еще может быть, но чтобы было 8 и все забиты это перебор.